# Identify the key value pair with duplicates in values of ansible dictionary

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory, ansible-facts, ansible-template

I have this dictionary:

```py
Ip = {'a':['one','two','three'],'b':['one','five','six'],'c':['seven','eight','nine'],'d':['five']}
```

And I wish my output to be like this

```py
Op = {'a':['one','two','three'],'b':['one','five','six'],'d':['five']}
```

Since it has some common values in the dictionary like 'one' or 'five', the duplicated value should be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        Op: "{{ Op|d({})|combine({item.key: Ip[item.key]}) }}"
      loop: "{{ Ip|dict2items }}"
      vars:
        _lists: "{{ Ip|dict2items|json_query('[].value') }}"
        _reduced: "{{ _lists|difference([item.value]) }}"
        _match: "{{ _reduced|map('intersect', item.value)|flatten }}"
      when: _match|length > 0
```

gives

```yaml
  Op:
    a:
    - one
    - two
    - three
    b:
    - one
    - five
    - six
    d:
    - five
```